# Magento 1.8 not recognizing forward slash after base_url (was working)

Tags: php, magento

I have noticed the issue when the CSS appeared to be broken. Heres what I have done:

1.) view source and noticed that forward slash "/" isn't being inserted after the URL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myfantasygifts.comjs/mt/extensions/jquery/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css" />
```

2.) also have checked phpmyadmin to be sure nothing has changed in the core_config_data table

[image]

3.) cleared out the contents within var/cache as well as var/session

4.) Logged into admin panel and reindexed Catalog URL Rewrites, this was a pain considering every click I had to manually add the forward slash after the domain.

5.) Changed permissions back to what magento requires
[resetting_file_permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)

6.) Checked all .htaccess files for url rewrite issue

7.) Cleared browser cache and tried in Google Chrome and Safari

I know that this has been posted numerous times and have tried numerous solutions that none of which seem to work so far. Any additional help will be greatly appreciated! And final, a huge Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding a https in your base url, or www after the http,  I had the same issue with Javascript and this fixed it for me.